# Use of strlen inside sprintf

Tags: printf, strlen

It it safe to use something like :
(when limit is so that no more then 512 chars are ever written, although a check should be placed here. )

```
char buffer[512]
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(char)*512)
for(int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
    sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%d,",i);
}
```

I'm curious about the possible transient effects of this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's safe.

In C, the arguments are evaluated before the function is called, meaning that the buffer + strlen(buffer) will be calculated before sprintf starts writing.

One remark though, you use sizeof(char) while memsetting the buffer, but you don't check sizeof(char) while shifting the pointer. You can either use:

```
buffer + sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer)
```

Or

```
&buffer[strlen(buffer)]
```

PS. However, it's rather safe to assume that sizeof(char) == 1, so your code is not wrong, just inconsistent.